# Programmatic authentication to the Artifactory API, via Okta

Tags: artifactory, okta-api

We're using SAML SSO with Okta, which has Desktop SSO (Kerberos).  I'm wondering if it's possible to get an access token for Artifactory's API programmatically, without prompting the user for credentials.

The Artifactory user guide mentions you can get an access token via the UI, but that's excessively disruptive to the user for my use-case.

Thanks.

Comment: is it possible you're confusing API KEY and Access Tokens? You can pragmatically get an Access Token via Artifactory APIs. Check if this helps: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CreateToken

Comment: @OrGat - that's the route that I'd like to use but it requires a username and password, which doesn't work well in an SSO environment.  Since users are already signed in to Okta via Desktop SSO and we sign into Artifactory using Okta, I'd like to write a script that can do the authentication and call the CreateToken route without prompting the user for credentials.

Comment: I doubt such an option will be made available before a user can create a token via Artifactory UI.

Comment: I doubt such an option will be made available before a user can create a token via Artifactory UI. Your user is logged in via SSO to the Artifactory APP but currently the only way to create a token is Artifactory APIs, which as you've said requires authentication (as it should).